# Umkehroperation zum Substantivieren

Tags: single-word-request, terminology, morphology, denominalization

Wenn ich aus einem Verb ein Substantiv mache, heißt das *substantivieren*:

> Ich warte. → Ich übe mich im Warten.

Wie aber nennt man den umgekehrten Prozess? Gibt es dafür einen eigenen Namen?

> Ich mache Worte daraus. → Ich verbalisiere es.

Gilt auch folgendes?

> Ich mache ein Verb daraus. → Ich verbalisiere es.

Comment: Das Beispiel ist falsch. Das Verb "verbalisieren" ist nicht vom Substantiv "Wort" abgeleitet. Eine Ableitung von "Wort" wäre: "Ich worte es." Und "verbalisieren" ist auch nicht von "Verb" abgeleitet, sondern vom französischen Verb "verbaliser" entlehnt, das wiederum vom Adjektiv "verbal" abgeleitet wurde, welches wiederum vom Lateinischen "verbalis" entlehnt wurde, und erst das ist vom Substantiv "verbum" abgeleitet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das wäre dann eine **Verbableitung**. Du leitest ein Verb ab.
Siehe auch: ["Verbableitung" bei Canoonet.eu](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-V/To-V-Intro.html)

**Verbifizieren** (von Verbifizierung) hätte den Vorteil, als transitives Verb zu funktionieren. Lustig kommt dagegen verbieren/Verbierung herüber. Prost.

Analog dazu: adjektivieren / Adjektivierung

**Desubstantivierung** wird generell die Ableitung von anderen Wortarten aus Substantiven genannt. Das kann als Gegenwort zu "Substantivierung" gelten.
 Siehe auch: ["Desubstantivierung" bei Wikipedia.](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desubstantivierung)

All dieses Ableiten von und Wörterbilden aus anderen Wörtern wird auch *Derivation* genannt, was ein Teil der *Morphologie / Formenlehre* einer Sprache ist.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn ein Wort, das kein Nomen ist, durch Nominalisierung und ohne formale Veränderung die Wortart wechselt, redet man von **Konversion**. 
Beispiele:

- warten (Verb) -> Warten (Substantiv)
- gegenüber (Präposition) -> (mein) Gegenüber (Substantiv)
- jetzt (Adverb) -> das Jetzt (Substantiv)
- wenn, aber (Konjunktionen) -> ohne Wenn und Aber (Substantive)
- Dank (Nomen) -> dank (Präposition)
- Frühstück (Nomen) -> frühstück(en) (Verb)
- Pfeffer (Nomen) -> pfeffern (Verb)
- locker (Adjektiv) -> lockern (Verb)

Die vier ersten Beispiele sind **Nominalisierungen** oder Substantivierungen.

Die drei letzten Beispiele nennt man **Verbalisierungen**; die Verben die so entstehen nennt man

- **desubstantivische Verben** oder **Desubstantiva** (Singular: Desubstantivum) wenn sie von einem Substantiv abgeleitet sind (z.B. pfeffern), bzw.
- **deadjektivische Verben** wenn sie von einem Adjektive abgeleitet sind (z.B. lockern).

Siehe z.B.:

- Hadumod Bußman (Hrsg.): *Lexikon der Sprachwissenschaft*. 4. Aufl.
  Stuttgart: Kröner, 2008.
- Dietrich Homberger: *Sachwörterbuch zur Sprachwissenschaft*.
  Stuttgart: Reclam, 2000.

(In den oben genannten Lexika kommen die Begriffe "Verbableitung" und "Verbifizierung" nicht vor.)

Answer (score 0):

[*Verbalisieren*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/verbalisieren) bedeutet, dass man aus einem Wort einer anderen Wortart ein Verb macht. Zwar üblicherweise mithilfe eines Suffixes, aber das muss nicht. Andererseits hat *verbalisieren* auch eine zweite Bedeutung im Sinne deines zweiten Beispiels.